# one to many pagination with subselect

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, pagination

Class looking like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
//@FetchProfiles({
public class Orders implements Serializable {

@Column
private String ...

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(..
//@OrderBy("sequence desc")
//@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<OrderedProducts> orderedProducts;
}
```

**case 1:** If i used one to many with eager/(lazy) then **subselect** working fine.

*Is it possible to do with fetch profiles? (only supporting join)*

**case 2:** For list data to get parent with child's with respect to limit(**pagination**). i am using subList feature in List (1000->25).

Example: one parent **more than one  child**
If i used max results 5 it is giving only **one record** if parent has 5 child's

*Can any one give me some idea to handle this scenario with hibernate criteria?*

**case 3:** If child property **annotated with order by** while execution time order by added before parent order specification

Example: order by child.prop,this_.prop

*Is there any other way to configure to parent property order then child properties order?*

Example: order by this_.prop,child.prop

**Note**
Iam sending data **outside** of the application scope. So, Lazy initialization wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**case 2**: 
Getting **all** list and split result with subList, its too bad approach what i thought.

Finally i did with one more additional query to get expected result **without** fetching all records from database.

**Approach:**

**1**. Fetch total count (with restrictions if any).

```
     Example: count=10000
```

*Note:* rowCount in Projections to get count

**2**. Fetch root entity primary key **id's** based on limit.

```
     Example: {1,2,...25} from 10000
```

*Note*: id() in projections to get only id's

**3**. Then, create aliases for all sub entities plus additional restriction property in primary key id's (**2**).

```
     Example: {----},{----}... from 10000 where property in (1,2,..25) -> 25 Full Objects
```